# Use SAS to read from GitHub or unzipping files

Tags: github, sas

I'm using SAS University Edition and the uploading max is 10mb.  I have some datasets in GitHub that are more than 10 mb. The files are in SAS .xpt format.  I'm trying to either read these into SAS directly from GitHub or upload them as .zip files and then unzip them in SAS to work with them.  I'm having trouble - please help.

Comment: Are you using SAS UE on AWS or running on your computer? If on your computer there is no such limitation. If on AWS, you can load your data into an S3 instance and access it that way. You can find the answers to these types of questions more so on communities.sas.com and the specific SAS UE forums.

Comment: xpt files are different than regular sas files so not sure how well this approach will work. https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2012/12/18/using-sas-to-access-data-stored-on-dropbox/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution if you want to get more than 10mb max is to run SAS University edition as a VM on your computer rather than the online version.

Other than that, you would have to break up your files into smaller ones if you wanted to still use the online edition.